# Deploy minfied javascript files and debug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, minify, gulp-uglify

so i completed building a new angular application and i would like to deploy it into production... of course i have prepared all my angular code such that it can be minified so i am covered there!! But something i dont understand... i have very good code separation and full unit testing of my application... as a result, of course, there are a lot of script tags on my main page.

I need to of course debug my javascript during runtime as i develop, but then when i go to deploy i need to minify. What is the best practice here? Is this literally a manually process of replacing the script tags with my all.min.js file after i move the code to the production machine? Do i minify all the css and html as well?? I am using gulp for the minification...

thanks for the help....

Comment: You could use a server side component that provides the script either in debug mode or release mode, depending on what you need.

Comment: Should not be a manual process. There are way too many ways to do it, which makes this question too broad for Stack Overflow. If you try something and get stuck, then you have a good question for this forum.

Comment: you don't need to minify html.

Comment: juan the question was not too broad at all... got some great answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of server side templating (like Razor or Thymeleaf) I would suggest using gulp-preprocess, gulp-processhtml, or gulp-html-replace.

Answer (score 1):

Use gulp to concat your files in development as well as production. You'll probably want to use [gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) to be able to debug your client-side javascript as if they were separate files.

Here's a sample `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('script', function(){
  gulp.src('./app/**/*.js')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(concat('application.js'))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
})

gulp.task('script:prod', function(){
  gulp.src('./app/**/*.js')
  .pipe(concat('application.js'))
  .pipe(ugilfy())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
})
```

Then in your view, just point it at the build file.

```
<script src="/build/application.js"></script>
```

When you deploy, run `gulp script:prod`. In development, run `gulp script`.